# Android studio add libs

Tags: android

I use "add as library" in Android studio, and it sets "compile files('libs/XXX.jar')" in "build.gradle". But it doesn't work!!!

It cost lots of my time. At last, I modify to "compile files('XXX.jar')"

But my jar is in directory "libs" as picture shows: [libs Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BADR.png)

Please tell me why!

[Here is the supplement picture of build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaehY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to your Gradle file and tell me if it worked :)

**edit**

or does it work but you don't understand why it works like this? Then it automatically assumes that your libraries are placed in that directory so you don't need to specify the libs/xxx.jar because it knows it should look in that directory anyways, so then it would search for libs/libs/xxx.jar instead of libs/xxx.jar. Hope that makes sense

Comment: There it was! But without use. T_T

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio click on Project Structure button to the right of Run Button,then click on the green + icon in the top right,choose Android Import Exiting Project[if the lib is .jar of .AAR choose Import . JAR or .AAR]then choose the lib and click finish,wait for gradle sync,then add the compile.Wish this helps

Comment: When I add jar through by Project Structure, it also set "compile files('libs/XXX.jar')" into build.gradle(notice: there has "libs/"). Right click and "add as library" is the same. I don't know why.